# Create custom radio button in IE

Tags: html, css

The following `CSS` styles can generate custom radio buttons in firefox and chrome, but the colors are gone in IE. How to fix that?

I have found a solution, which uses `:checked::-ms-check`, but the `background-color` is also gone.

```css
.group {
    background-color: #FF9BFF;
}

.radioBtnCtrl {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.radioBtnLabel {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 34px;
  
    width: 100px;
    color: #58860B;
}

input[type="radio"].radioBtn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #00ff00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    outline: none;
  
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="radio"].radioBtn:checked::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    content: "";
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <label class="radioBtnCtrl" role="radio">
        <input type="radio" aria-label="accept" class="radioBtn" name="A" value="accept" checked>
        <span class="radioBtnLabel">accept</span>
    </label>
    <label class="radioBtnCtrl" role="radio">
        <input type="radio" aria-label="reject" class="radioBtn" name="A" value="reject">
        <span class="radioBtnLabel">reject</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE can be very tricky to style right. There are several things to be careful about:

1: When you try your Site on your local PC jsut by using a webserver like laragon or just display it inside your browser without any server it gets treated as "intranet-site" which means IE changes its compatibility check to IE5 or IE7 etc. you can see that when you open the webtools (F12), there is a dropdown on the top right that display the number of the current simulated IE-Version. Make sure that is set to IE11 or whatever version you want it to be displayed in.

2: The CSS wont work for IE cause IE doesnt support a lot of useful CSS properties.

3: I ususally fix this customized Radio-Button Styling by faking the buttons and using Jquery to swap classes. Example:

```js
$('#label1').click(function(){
    console.log('click');
    $('.buttonlabel').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).closest('.buttonlabel').addClass('clicked');
    $('#radio1').prop('checked', true);
});
$('#label2').click(function(){
    console.log('click');
    $('.buttonlabel').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).closest('.buttonlabel').addClass('clicked');
    $('#radio2').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```css
body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
.customRadio {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.radio-group {
    background-color: bisque;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
}
#radio1{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
.buttonlabel{
    width: 20px;
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: green;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.clicked {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="customRadio">
    <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="radio" checked>
        <div id="label1" class="buttonlabel"></div>
        <span>accept</span>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" class="radio" checked>
        <div id="label2" class="buttonlabel"></div>
        <span>reject</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see i positioned the "label-Divs" on top of the Radio button and change the selected radio-button with Jquery. So i click the div not the radio and style the div. There are lots of discussions about the possibility to use pure CSS on IE but i havent seen a working example yet. So this is all i can offer you sadly. Maybe that still helps you or atleast gives you a bit of insight why it doesn't work.
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I can use another element to accept click event and add styles on it to "mock" as a radio button.